# Can't run COMPSs application. ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hpc, compss

I am learning COMPSs. Until now, everything has been working really well, but I only executed the examples given in the manual.

Now that I want to run my own test application, I can't get it to work. I must be missing something, but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

My application is called App, and has the main class App, and the interface in another class called AppItf. When I try to run it using runcompss:

> runcompss -d --classpath=$PWD/App.jar App

I get the following message:

> Using default location for project file:
>   /opt/COMPSs/Runtime/scripts/user/../../configuration/xml/projects/project.xml
>   Using default location for resources file:
>   /opt/COMPSs/Runtime/scripts/user/../../configuration/xml/resources/resources.xml
>
> ----------------- Executing App --------------------------
>
> [Loader]  -  There was an error when loading or executing your
>   application. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at integratedtoolkit.loader.ITAppLoader.load(ITAppLoader.java:54)
>           at integratedtoolkit.loader.ITAppLoader.main(ITAppLoader.java:84) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AppItf
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at integratedtoolkit.loader.CustomLoader.loadClass(CustomLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
>           at integratedtoolkit.loader.total.ITAppModifier.modify(ITAppModifier.java:46)
>           ... 6 more
>
> Error running application

Can somebody help me find what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AppItf. Have you defined the Task definition interface?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is a very simple interface with just one task. But it says it does not find it. And I made sure the are no typos in the class names and the classpath is correct...it is quite weird

Comment: Is your main class inside a package?

Comment: Uhmmm...I think so. It is inside a package named app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the runcompss command you have to specify the fully qualified domain name of the class. So, if this class has a package you have to add the package to the class name. It is currently missing.

Comment: Yes! That was the error! 
The runcompss line that worked is:  
runcompss -d --classpath=$PWD/App.jar app.App  
I just had to add "app" before the main class name. Thank you very much!